# Fill select onchange function id with the data of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the next code:

```
<div class="form-group question" id="encuesta[ENC_ID]" value="ENC_ID" name="encuesta" data-encuesta_id="ENC_ID" style="border-radius: 3px;border-color: #5e5e5e;border: 1px;
border-style: solid;padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-11">
        <h5>Pregunta <div id="preg_num" name="preg_num" class="preg_num">ENC_ID</div></h5><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" onclick="deletePreg(ENC_ID);"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <label for="enc_nombre">Tipo de pregunta: </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <select class="form-control" onchange="cambioOpc(ENC_ID);" id="tipo[ENC_ID]" name="question_type[ENC_ID]">
          <option value="input" selected>Texto abierto</option>
          <option value="radio">Seleccionar una</option>
          <option value="checkbox">Seleccionar varias</option>
        </select></div>
```

This code is to create questions and add the amount of questions that the user requires, and when the page loads for the first time all the html that contains the text "ENC_ID" is changed by an id, the problem is that when a question is deleted by the user I do not know how to change the id of the select to put the same id that has the main div **"data-encuesta_id"**

JS of the file to delete questions:

```
function deletePreg(idENC){
$('div.question').each(function(i, obj)
{
    $(obj).find('.preg_num').text(i + 1);
    pregNum = i + 1;
    if(idENC == $(obj).data('encuesta_id')){
        $(obj).remove();
    }
});
reenumerarPreguntas();}
function reenumerarPreguntas(){
$('div.question').each(function(i, obj){
    $(obj).find('.preg_num').text(i + 1);
    pregNum = i + 1;
    $(obj).data('encuesta_id', i+1);
});}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recommendation:**

In your `<select>`, move "tipo" as a class and remove the id. Put the ENCID in as a data attribute. Like so:

`<select class="form-control tipo" onchange="cambioOpc(ENC_ID);" data-enc-id="[ENC_ID]" name="question_type[ENC_ID]">`

Now you can reference the select by class + data attribute value and change the data attribute instead.

**Example:** `$('.tipo[data-enc-id="'+idENC+'"]').data('enc-id', new_enc_id);`

---

**How to change ID in loop**:

> If you *really* have to change the id, you can this like so:

**Example:**

`$('#tipo'+idENC).prop('id', 'tipo'+new_enc_id_here);`

**`OR`**

`$('#tipo'+idENC).attr('id', 'tipo'+new_enc_id_here);`

Comment: Great! I am glad that I could help. Would you mind marking this as the answer? Have a great day!